# Applying Single Table Inheritance

Tags: database-design, single-table-inheritance

From [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661637/mvc-design-convention-cruding-inherited-models) question:

[image: database structure]

Summarizing:

- My CRUDs are: customers, employees and branches.
- `Customer`s and `Employee`s are associated with one `Person`, one `Individual` (fields related to the person itself) and one `User` (for login purposes). So `Individual`s and `User`s are always related to one `Customer` or `Employee` person.
- `Branch`es are associated with one `Person` and one `Company` (fields related to the corporate person). So `Company`s are always related to one `Branch` person. They didn't have an user because they're affiliated to the company that this database stands for - it's their employees who can authenticate into the app.
- An `Employee` belongs to one `Branch`. A `Branch` has zero or many `Employee`s. *(yeah, diagram is incorrect, sorry!)*
- Currently I'm using a single bit to diff `Employee` role - I've employees with operational and administrative rights. Roles permissions goes in the code itself, and here you can realize that customers also have their own role... Any suggestions to implement a better (and simple) way to manage that roles for both customers and employees?

How should I change that *wrong* 3NF structure to achieve a well designed single table inheritance for a better use of MVC pattern?

I tried to simplify a bit, and now I accomplished this new structure:

[image: new database structure]

Can I still improve it? Where? How would you model that?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new table for city is only worthwhile if you have normal-low cardinality (fewer unique / more repeats). So depending on your users, you will have to decide on your own. On the other hand, you can break away Address table and phone number table.

Depending on what kind of information you are storing about employee and customers, you can have just a field indicating if the person if employee or customer or can have two separate tables.

If we talk about roles, they usually denotes the authority / position / accessibility of an employee. I.e. Regular, P/T, Manager. You can develop the access levels & visibility of the content for each group / role.

Take out all personal details from Person and store them in a new table. (Just curious.. DO you REALLY need `nickname` field? Disk I/O is one of the largest bottleneck of any application) separate personal details from professional details and IDs.

Talking about Branch, are you sure that there will be only one contact at any time? Usually, that is not the case in the business world. But a branch / person will have ONLY ONE address at any given time, so here your separate address table will be helpful.

It's really hard to suggest a structure in general. A good design is always based on the business rules.